# Excel VBA altera o formato da data para mm/dd/yyyy

Tags: microsoft-excel, excel-vba

Estou desenvolvendo uma planilha em `Excel` utilizando o `VBA`, que funcionará como um "micro-sistema" de cadastro.

Estou com o seguinte problema: toda vez que eu digito a data na célula `Cad_0`, por exemplo, o Excel altera o formato para  `mm/dd/yyyy`.

Na mesma planilha já estou utilizando um código para que o `Excel` altere  os textos digitados em minúsculos para maiúsculo.

Se eu excluir esse código, o `Excel` para de alterar o formato da data.

Comment: Como você altera estes dígitos? Poderia informar o código que você está utilizando? Editando a pergunta com o código.

Answer (score 1):

Segue modelo abaixo, convertendo datas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
Dim CData As Date  
Dim CData2 As Date  

{'--- MODELO 01}  
Sub DataCompra1()  

    [C8].Select
    CData = [C8].Value

    If CData = "0" Then
        MsgBox "INFORME A DATA"
        'Exit Sub '--- ESTA FUNÇÃO PARA O SCRIPT, CASO QUEIRA UTILIZAR DESCOMENTE A LINHA
    Else
        ActiveCell.Value = ""
        Selection.Offset(0, 2).Select
        ActiveCell.Value = CData

    End If

End Sub

{'--- MODELO 02}  
Sub DataCompra2()  

    Dim CData As Date
    Dim CHora As Date

    dt = [C8].Value
    'fmt = [C8].Value
    CData = Format(dt)
    CHora = Format(Now)
    'Format (fmt)

    [E8].Value = CData
    [E9].Value = CHora

End Sub

Sub LimparData()

[C8].Value = ""
[E8].Value = ""

End Sub
```